# Conditional branch never validated in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

In my conditional branch, I never fit in the validated condition, despite that the parameters are good, or at least seem good to me.

I am checking the contents of a database table variable `paramtragetable` as well as a source file name variable `fichiersource`. Everything seems coherent to me, as attached on the captures.

Do you see where the problem can come from?

[image: capture1]

[image: capture2]

---

OK, sorry if I'm not clear.

I have 4 initial variables: `Base PostgreSQL`, `Paramétrage Schéma`, `Paramétrage table` and `Fichier Source`.
The first 3 are database type entries. Source file is vector layer type (I load a layer). I want to check the values ​​of these variables.

The **Vérification du schéma** condition checks that the schema of the selected database variable is the correct one for the script. Ditto for **Vérification vidange** which checks the table of the database variable. These 2 conditions work correctly.
The **Vérification source** condition verifies that the loaded layer name does indeed contain a certain defined value (in my example epci.shp).

But the formula `@fichiersource LIKE '%epci.shp'` is never true, we always enter the condition `@fichiersource **NOT LIKE** '%epci.shp'`, while the log tells me that the variable @fichiersource = ' C:/GIS/Data/Administrative/EPCI/epci.shp', therefore contains "epci.shp".

Is it clearer?

Comment: Be sure to select Dependencies (click `...`) in the algorithm that should be based on the conditional branch and check the box next to the condition you want to apply. See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/446293/88814

Comment: The conditional branch does not depend on any algorithm! this is the first step, in order to know if the script can continue or not. But I don't think that prevents it from seeing the values of the variables, does it?

Comment: I think you should make the conditional branch make dependent on an algorithm, this seems to be the logic of the tool.

Comment: see: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/index.html#feature-new-modeler-algorithm-for-creating-conditional-branches

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, there is indeed an algorithm connected (`vidange de la table`) to the conditional branch by the dependencies, but the problem is not there.
The problem is that the conditional branch `Vérification source` itself is never "ok" despite the upstream variable `Fichier source` looking correct.

[image: capture]

Myybe I'm not going at all well to check the value of the source file (input vector layer parameter), and that I have to use another tool to know the name of the loaded layer?...

Comment: So this is part of the question, not an answer? In this case, edit the initial post an paste this there. To me, it's still not clear what exactly you want: can you describe a bit clearer what condition you want to apply where?